# Why we need Nodejs before setup Phonegap?

Tags: node.js, phonegap-plugins

I came across the site of Phonegap and in site they told us to install nodejs before setup Phonegap I actually can't understand why we need nodejs installed before starting Phonegap?

Comment: Because the Phonegap CLI is built using JavaScript and runs on Node.js...

Comment: What is the proper meaning of CLI?

Comment: Command Line Interface - providing instructions via the terminal

Comment: Means that I can't run phonegap using .net technology like visual studio visually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the phonegap is built with nodejs and if you check out phonegap cli source code you can see this

> PhoneGap command-line interface and Node.js library.

[Phonegap github source code](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-cli)

Comment: Can I run phonegap using .net technology visualy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use .Net as Backend for Phonegap application, you do Not "run" using .Net.

Have a look at Phonegap FAQ

> A PhoneGap application may only use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, you can make use of network protocols (XmlHTTPRequest, Web Sockets, etc) to easily communicate with backend services written in any language. This allows your PhoneGap app to remotely access existing business processes while the device is connected to the Internet.

http://phonegap.com/about/faq/